# Azure function deployed with Dotnet 6 from Visual Studio 2022 doesn't work

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

So I have a basic function. The code can be seen below. I can run it locally without any problems. I can call it from a browser and from postman. But when I run a basic deploy to Azure Functions, it says deploy success, but I am not able to call it from browser or postman. I have remembered to make the function AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous so I dont have to include apikey or any auth.

I have tried to deploy this function to several regions and both to Windows and Linux futions.

https://someawesomefunction20211215085831.azurewebsites.net/api/Swag

vs

http://localhost:7071/api/Swag

*Edit:

Added GIF of prod not working with default settings from deploy from Visual Studio.

[image]

My deployed function doesn't show up on the functions overview??? Could this be the problem?

[image]

```
public static class Awesomeness
{
    [FunctionName("Swag")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: We tested this in our local environment, created a simple http trigger function with .net 6  in visual studio 2022. we are able to trigger the http function using postman in our local & in portal with .net6  as well.
1. Reference image when we trigger function from [local through postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNZpw.png).
2. Reference image when we trigger the same Http function which is [hosted on Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJUoc.png).

Comment: I have just created a new project. Deployed it with default settings. But I can never call it on azure. Added gif showing default settings and all.

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT > Your screenshot shows that you can see / test your Azure fuctions inside the portal. I don't see my Azure function in that overview. Only the AppService above.

Comment: @Kiksen- lets join this chat room to discuss further https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/240170/room-for-venkateshdodda-mt-and-kiksen

Comment: Can you confirm you're using Azure Functions runtime v4.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved post closing the solution & opening it again in visual studio 2022. Suggested them to enable run from package file while publishing the function from local to Azure function app . Post that user is able to see the function under the function app & able to trigger the function it from the post man as well.